# Effiecient serialization of native java arrays with java.io

Tags: java, performance, serialization, fileoutputstream, hard-drive

i gotta question about Java Serialization.

I'm simply writing out 10 arrays of size int[] array = new int[2^28] to my harddik (i know that's kinda big, but i need it that way) using a FileOutputStream and a BufferedOutputStream in combination with a Dataoutputstream. Before each serialization i create a new FileOutputstream and all the other streams and afterwards i close and flush my streams.

Problem:
The first serialization takes about 2 seconds, afterwards it increases up tp 17seconds and stays on this level. What's the problem here? If i go into the code i can see that the FileOutputStreams take a huge amount of time for writeByte(...). Is this due to the HDD caching (full)? How can i avoid this? Can i clear it?

Here is my simple code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("### Starting test");

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        System.out.println("### Run nr ... " + k);

        // Creating the test array....
        int[] testArray = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, 28)];

        for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                testArray[i] = i;
            }
        }

        BufferedDataOutputStream dataOut = new BufferedDataOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("e:\\test" + k + "_" + 28 + ".dat"));

        // Serializing...
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        dataOut.write(testArray);

        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000.0
                + " s");

        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.close();
    }
}
```

where dataOut.write(int[], 0, end)

```
    public void write(int[] i, int start, int len) throws IOException {

    for (int ii = start; ii < start + len; ii += 1) {
        if (count + 4 > buf.length) {
            checkBuf(4);
        }

        buf[count++] = (byte) (i[ii] >>> 24);
        buf[count++] = (byte) (i[ii] >>> 16);
        buf[count++] = (byte) (i[ii] >>> 8);
        buf[count++] = (byte) (i[ii]);

    }

}
```

and `protected void checkBuf(int need) throws IOException {

```
    if (count + need > buf.length) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
        count = 0;
    }
}`
```

BufferedDataOutputStream extends BufferedOutputStream comes along with the fits framework. It simply combines the BufferedOutputStream with the DataOutputStream to reduce the number of method calls when you write big arrays (which makes it a lot faster... up to 10 times ...).

Here is the output:

> Starting benchmark
>
> #### STARTING RUN 0
>
> 2.001972271
>
> #### STARTING RUN 1
>
> 1.986544604
>
> #### STARTING RUN 2
>
> 15.663881232
>
> #### STARTING RUN 3
>
> 17.652161328
>
> #### STARTING RUN 4
>
> 18.020969301
>
> #### STARTING RUN 5
>
> 11.647542466
>
> #### STARTING RUN 6

Why the time is so much increasing?

Thank you,

Eeth

Answer (score 4):

In this program I populate 1 GB as int values and "force" these to be written to disk.

```
String dir = args[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  File tmp = new File(dir, "deleteme." + i);
  tmp.deleteOnExit();
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(tmp, "rw");
  final MappedByteBuffer map = raf.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 30);
  IntBuffer array = map.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
  for (int n = 0; n < array.capacity(); n++)
    array.put(n, n);

  map.force();

  ((DirectBuffer) map).cleaner().clean();
  raf.close();
  long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
  System.out.printf("Took %.1f seconds to write 1 GB%n", time / 1e9);
}
```

with each file forced to disk, they take about the same amount of time each.

```
Took 7.7 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.5 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.7 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.9 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.6 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.7 seconds to write 1 GB
```

However, if I comment out the `map.force();` I see this profile.

```
Took 0.8 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 1.0 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 4.9 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.2 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.0 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.2 seconds to write 1 GB
Took 7.2 seconds to write 1 GB
```

It appears that it will buffer about 2.5 GB which is about 10% of my main memory before it slows down.

---

You can clear you cache by waiting for the previous writes to finish.

Basically you have 1 GB of data and the sustain write speed of your disk appears to be about 60 MB/s which is reasonable for a SATA Hard Drive.  If you get speeds higher than this its because the data hasn't really written to disk and is actually in memory.

If you want to this to be faster you can use a memory mapped file.  This has the benefit of writing to disk in background as you are populating the "array" i.e. it can be finished writing almost as soon as you finish setting the values.

Another option is to get a faster drive. A single 250 GB SSD drive can sustain writes of around 200 MB/s.  Using multiple drives in a RAID configuration can also increase write speed.

Comment: Hi Again, I just edited my previous post, i gave you more information. I actually have a SSD. So you think not everything is written when I do my measurement? how can I check this?!

Comment: Watch disk write activity. When the disk activity stops, all the data has been written. On Unix try `iostat 2`. My guess is that this is about 8 second you finish writing your data.  Not all SSD drives are the same speed and I tend to find you get about half the read speed and one quarter the write they suggest they can do.

Comment: @Eeth, I have added a program which uses memory mapped files. This supports `force()`ing the data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The first writes may just be filling up your hard drive's cache without actually writing to disk yet.